# statsmodel ARIMA dynamic forecasting with exogenous regressor

Tags: python, dynamic, statsmodels, arima

I am trying to use multivariate arima for the prediction of the `price` column. I am training arima model on `[train_start_index:train_end_index]` and later I am using the parameters of it to predict new data.

```
while (train_end_index < inputNumber - 1):
        train_end_index = train_start_index + trainLength
        test_start_index = train_end_index
        test_end_index= test_start_index + horizon
        if (filteredData[test_start_index:test_end_index]["day"].values[-1] > 300) and (filteredData[test_start_index:test_end_index]["year"].values[-1] == 2017):
            return predictions, prices
        trainFeatures = filteredData[train_start_index:train_end_index]["totaltx"]
        trainOutput = filteredData[train_start_index:train_end_index]["price"]

        training_arima = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(endog=trainOutput, exog=trainFeatures, order=(window, 1, 1), trend="ct", initialization='approximate_diffuse')
        training_arima_fit = training_arima.fit(disp=0)

        testFeatures = filteredData[train_start_index:test_end_index]["totaltx"]
        testOutput = filteredData[train_start_index:test_end_index]["price"]

        test_arima = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(endog=testOutput, exog=testFeatures, order=(window, 1, 1), trend="ct", initialization='approximate_diffuse')
        #res = test_arima.filter(training_arima_fit.params)
        res=test_arima.smooth(training_arima_fit.params)

        predicted = res.predict()[-1:]
        price = filteredData[test_start_index:test_end_index]["price"].values[-1:]

        predictions = np.append(predictions, predicted.values)
        prices = np.append(prices, price)
```

However, I have a problem here. For predicting the `Price(t+horizon)`, I assume that I have not the value of `TotalTx(t),...,TotalTx(t+horizon)`. I just want to predict the Price(t+horizon) with the previously trained arima. However, arima needs the exogenous variables for `TotalTx(t),...,TotalTx(t+horizon)`.

Is it possible to suggest me arima model in python with exogenous regressor to fix the issue?

Thanks.